# C programming - compiler tells me I am dereferencing an incomplete type

Tags: c, types, struct

The structure of code is I have a struct "entry", which is stored within a circular list "bucket", which is stored within a hash table. An "entry" has two fields (a and b), and when I search for field a and return field b, I'm trying to do it in the following way:

```
ht_lookup(d.dict->items[bucket],field_a)
```

I have searched on this and the solution seems to be to include the header file which defines the bucket, but I have included the header file which defines bucket, i.e. the circular list, so I don't understand how the type is incomplete. Is there something I can do with the code as it is to render the type complete?

I am at my wit's end, any help really appreciated.

```
struct dictionary
{
  ht *   dict;
} d;

struct entry
{
  char   word[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
  char   desc[MAX_DESC_SIZE];
};
```

This is after

```
`#include "ht.h"`
```

Which is where the hash table is defined, which is what each bucket is:

```
ht * new_ht(int max, hashfun h1, getkeyfun getkey)
{
int i;
ht * t = (ht*)malloc(sizeof(ht));
t->items = (clist**)malloc(max * sizeof(clist*));
t->size = 0;
t->h1 = h1;
t->getkey = getkey;
t->max = max;
for (i=0; i<max; i++)
    t->items[i] = new_clist();
return t;
}
```

gcc is outputting this error:

error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: show your code (where the list bucket is defined) and (at least) the line where the compiler throws the error (including the error message). Otherwise we might just guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Please show your struct and struct members definition.

Comment: Edited the post to move the `^` out of the code line so it doesn't look like a syntax error.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

`d.dict` is a pointer to something, the definition of this something is missing to the compiler. `d` is of type of some `struct` that contains a `dict` member, that is a pointer to some (possibly) other `struct`. The definition of this other `struct` is missing in the compilation unit.